# GET request google

Tags: c, sockets, post, browser, get

I'm trying to implement a simple web browser in C.
When ever I send a get request to google.com using

```
    GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n
```

I receive

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Location: http://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=1wIjWPqZA6DmugSY4I-IDw
Content-Length: 261
Date: Wed, 09 Nov 2016 11:04:55 GMT

<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>302 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>302 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="http://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&amp;ei=1wIjWPqZA6DmugSY4I-IDw">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
```

Subsequently I send another GET request

```
GET /?gfe_rd=cr&amp;ei=1wIjWPqZA6DmugSY4I-IDw HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n
```

And I receive error code 404 not found.

If not this, what should be the GET request to redirect me to the site. I find ip address of google using

```
char *hostname = "www.google.com";
struct hostent *he;
he = gethostbyname( hostname );
```

Comment: I think you need to resolve ip address of `www.google.co.in` for the second request.

Comment: That doesn't work either. Keeps on replying with This document has been MOVED

Answer (score 1):

You're requesting the wrong URL.

Take a closer look at the URL given in the `Location` header:

```
http://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=1wIjWPqZA6DmugSY4I-IDw
```

and the URL in the HTML source:

```
http://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&amp;ei=1wIjWPqZA6DmugSY4I-IDw
```

You'll notice that the second of these is slightly different, because ampersands have to be encoded as `&amp;` in HTML documents.

If you use the URL in the `Location` header, you stand a better chance of success. However, you might still have problems if the server's behaviour depends on other factors. For example, a lot of websites will reject requests without a recognisable `User-Agent` request header.

Comment: Alright I see your logic, I tried changing the &amp; to & but still it didn't work. Probably my User-Agent is not defined thats why it doesn't work.

Comment: @kaiser You should also consider sending other headers such as `Referer` and `Accept`. The more  your code behaves like an ordinary browser, the better your chances of getting a valid response.